# Add new items to checkboxlist dynamically from a List<> C#

Tags: c#, dynamically-generated, checkedlistbox

I don't want to add items from the collection HARD-CODED style, I want to populate them from a List<> when a button is pressed.

First i took data from the list like this:

```
private List<User> _users = new List<User>()

foreach (User user in _users) {
    int index = checkedListBoxDepts.Items.Add(user.UserName);
    upd.checkedListBoxDepts.Items[index] = user;
}
```

FOR the retrieval of checked items: (I put them in a List of type string):

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in checkedListBoxDepts.CheckedItems) {
    Names.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Looks ok, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I get an index error, Index out of range, at : index or the checkboxlist doesn't show anything...@nvoigt

Comment: Solved... users was null; so of course the checkedListBox was null..

Answer (score 5):

You're getting error because of this line:

```
upd.checkedListBoxDepts.Items[index] = user;
```

You're assigning user object to the checkBoxList's items, then trying to retrieve them as strings

This is enough to populate:

```
private List<User> _users = new List<User>()

foreach (User user in _users) {
    checkedListBoxDepts.Items.Add(user.UserName);
}
```

You can retrieve checked items as strings afterwards

Comment: when I checked with the debugger, still the field of checkedListBoxDepts was still SelectedIndex =-1...and still the index error...@nvoigt

Comment: Why you're checking SelectedIndex property ? You're using CheckedItems property, if there is no checked item, collection is empty and you would not get an exception.

Comment: I cant see any items on the form.. so they cant be checked...@yclkvnc

Comment: @Paradigm Are yoıu sure you use the correct CheckedListBox ? I suggest you to create a new Windows Form project and try out there.